# Trigger event when column header menu filter checkbox is checked/unchecked in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I currently have no access to the column header menu xtype (since it is not exposed?), and for that reason I cannot add a listener to it in order to catch a checkchange event.

```
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                id: 'stagesEnteredQueue',
                align: 'center',
                dataIndex: 'enteredQueue',
                text: 'Entered Queue',
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                filter: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                },
                renderer: function (val, metaData, record) {
                    val = Ext.Date.format(val, 'd/m/Y, H:i:s');
                    return val;
                },
                minWidth: 150,
                flex: 1
            }
```

How can I catch a check/uncheck event on the column header filter menu? The changes to the store filter it is automatically executing need to be changed due to business rules of my app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a filterchange event in gridpanel.
You can read the documentation here:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-filterchange

Comment: I am currently using that event for other purposes. Actually, that one is called whenever the store filter has changed. I want to be able to catch the check/uncheck of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are working in 6.5 then user below listeners 
 listeners:{
            filteractivate:function( this, column, eOpts ) {
                //TODO indetify by column
            },
             filterdeactivate:function( this, column, eOpts ) {
                //TODO indetify by column
            }
        }

Note: Add a listener on the grid, not on the column.
Source https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/src/Base.js-10.html#Ext.panel.Table-event-filteractivate
```